# node-restful not saving Document "contents" to MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am trying to save a document to MongoDb using NodeJS.
I am using Express, Mongoose, Node-Restful to do the hard work for me. However, although it does create the document in the MongoDb their is no actual content. I only get

> [
>       {
>           "_id": "5460ab83c9e8f9481063df82",
>           "__v": 0
>       },
>       {
>           "_id": "5460ac00c9e8f9481063df83",
>           "__v": 0
>       },
>       {
>           "_id": "5460ae36c9e8f9481063df85",
>           "__v": 0
>       },
>       {
>           "__v": 0
>       },
>       {
>           "_id": "5460afb6be7938bc1469ae97",
>           "__v": 0
>       },
>       {
>           "_id": "5460fe9088d68e2516cdf572",
>           "__v": 0
>       },
>       {
>           "_id": "5460fecfd47cba3916fba0ab",
>           "__v": 0
>       },
>       {
>           "_id": "5460fed5d47cba3916fba0ac",
>           "__v": 0
>       },
>       {
>           "_id": "5460fed8d47cba3916fba0ad",
>           "__v": 0
>       },
>       {
>           "_id": "5460ff079b60285016dfd0da",
>           "__v": 0
>       }
>   ]

As you can see the actual content is not being saved which for testing purposes is only a name.

**My Schema (models/users.js)**

```
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String
});


module.exports = restful.model('user',userSchema );
```

**My api (api/api.js)**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var userModel = require('../models/users')

userModel.methods(['get','put','post','delete']);
userModel.register(router,'/user');

module.exports = router;
```

**and the app code (server.js)**

```
console.log("Adding Requires");
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var urlEncoded = require('urlencoded-request-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var override = require('method-override');
var rest = require('node-restful');

console.log("Creating Server Object");
var server = express();
server.locals.moment = require('moment');
server.set('ServerVersion', "5.0.1.7");

console.log("Server setting port");
var port = process.env.port || 1337;

console.log("Connecting to MongooseDB");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://mvm-mongodb.cloudapp.net/ccslabs-main");

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB successfully');
});


server.disable('x-powered-by');

console.log("Server setting uses");
server.use(urlEncoded());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(override());


console.log("Server setting routes");
var routePath="./routes/"; 
fs.readdirSync(routePath).forEach(function(file) {
    var route=routePath+file;
    console.log("\tAdding routes: " + route)
    require(route)(server);
});

console.log("\tAdding API routes");
server.use('/api',require('./api/api'));

console.log("\tAdding Static Files routes");
server.use(express.static(__dirname + "/content"));

console.log("Server creating sets");
server.set('view engine', 'ejs');
server.set('views', __dirname);

server.listen(port);
console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
```

**The output from nodemon on running server.js is**

```
Adding Requires
Creating Server Object
Server setting port
Connecting to MongooseDB
Server setting uses
Server setting routes
        Adding routes: ./routes/home.js
        Adding routes: ./routes/login.js
        Adding routes: ./routes/submission.js
        Adding routes: ./routes/testing.js
        Adding API routes
        Adding Static Files routes
Server creating sets
Server listening on port 1337
Connected to MongoDB successfully
```

I populate the db using Postman chrome extension an empty document is created without the data I posted in the form of a key value pair. name "dave"

[image: Postman output]

So to summarise I send data to the mongodb via node-restuful and mongoose however, although the document is created it does not contain the data. Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: Having the same problem. I'll put a bounty on this soon if you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a header in postman of

`Content-Type : application/json`

and instead of using form fields, send it with as raw json. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I never comment on stackoverflow but this was an issue for me several times and I seem to keep running into this. So, I'll like to HELP everyone.

First Set Header to `Content-Type : application/json`

Don't include `:` into `Context-type`.

Second choose raw for the input type. Though this isn't a JSON tutorial, postman notice the difference between single and double quotes.

Use double quotes which is this `"`, NOT `'` and not `''`. Second, double quote the key and if the value of the key is a string, double quote the expression.

It was always recommended that keys should be single strings (use camel hump notation if necessary). Being a so-called veteran of programming,

I though postman would handle if the keys for the JSON object was variables  and not string because of the notation but maybe it is an issue with postman. A picture tells a  thousand words so I included a picture.

Note that if you have issues add particular key, it might be your model. Go young grasshopper. (A)lways (B)e (C)oding

Regards!

Quentin Mayo.

**P.S I have no affiliation with Postman but I strongly recommend it to anyone trying to work with an API.**

I don't post enough to post images so if someone validates me, feel free to post re-post the image on this page(I just want to help others).
http://postimg.org/image/6xmto3elj/

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was selecting **x-www-form-urlencoded** rather than the default selection of **form-data**